# Use Javascript to alert highest and lowest integers from user input

Tags: javascript, function, integer, comparison

New to JS, trying to complete an assignment which calls for a user to input their age and use Javascript to:

1. Check that the input is a valid integer;
2. If the entered age is the lowest one entered so far, or the highest entered so far, alert a message saying so (i.e. "This is the lowest age we've seen!" / "This is the highest age we've seen.").

I've been able to get #1, but I can't figure out where to even begin with #2. I've logged the numbers from the input to the console, as I'd image comparisons will be made from there. I've started trying to sketch out the  alertAge() function, but don't know where to take it.

What is the best way to go about this?

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", checkAge);
   
      
function checkAge() {
    var ages = document.getElementById("age").value;

    if (isNaN(ages)) {
        alert("Value must be a number. Try again!");
    }
    else {
        console.log(ages);
    }  

}

function alertAge() {
    var highest;
    var lowest;

    if (highest === undefined) {   // This is the first age we're seeing
        highest = age;
        lowest = age;
    } else {
        if (age > highest)
            highest = age;   // This is the new highest age
        if (age < lowest)
            lowest = age;    // This is the new lowest age
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="age">Enter your age:</label>
  <input id="age" />
  <button id="myButton" type="submit">Go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/lasirep/edit?html,js,output

Comment: If you create/instantiate vars inside of your method, then they won't exist the next time your method is called ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you could use `<input type="number">` instead of checking in JS if it's a number.

For #2, you need to store your values outside of the function. [Read more about Javascript context](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/).
To use a variable *outside* of the function, do like so:

```
    var highest,lowest;
    function alertAge() {...};
```

---

More precise explaination:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="age">Enter your age:</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" />
  <button onClick="checkAge()">Go</button>
  <script>
    var highest = null;
    var lowest = null;

    function alertAge(age) {
      if (!highest) {
          highest = lowest = age;
      } else {
          if (age > highest) {
            highest = age;   // This is the new highest age
            alert('new highest', age);
          }
          if (age < lowest) {
            lowest = age;    // This is the new lowest age
            alert("new lowest", age);
          }
      }
    }

    function checkAge() {
        var ages = document.getElementById("age").value;
        if (ages) alertAge(ages);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- `<input type="number">` restricts to number only.
- `onClick="checkAge()"` calls checkAge() whenever that element is clicked (doesn't have to be a button).
- `highest = lowest = age;` sets lowest to 'age' and sets highest to lowest (which is 'age'). Write less, you're going to need your energy :)
- `alert('my text')` is the typical javascript popup "alert".
- `if (ages)` condition is there to make sure we don't send weird things to alertAge();
- declaring the `highest` and `lowest` variables outside of the function makes them "kind of" permament, it allows you to use them even when the function is finished. If you declare a variable within a function, that variable ceases to exist once the function has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since u want to save your highest or lowest age in the functions, u need to put then in a closure.

Try this.

```
var alertAge = function() {
            var highest;
            var lowest;
            return function(age){
                if (highest === undefined) {   // This is the first age we're seeing
                    highest = age;
                    lowest = age;
                } else {
                    if (age > highest)
                        highest = age;   // This is the new highest age
                        // alert here
                    if (age < lowest)
                        lowest = age;    
                        // alert here
                }
            };
        }();
```

Then you can

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var highest = null;
                var lowest = null;

                function checkAge() {
                    var ages = document.getElementById("age").value;

                    if (isNaN(ages)) {
                        alert("Value must be a number. Try again!");
                    }
                    else {
                        alertAge(ages);
                        alert("highest="+highest+"\nlowest="+lowest);
                        console.log(ages);
                    }       

                }

                function alertAge(age) {

                    if (highest === null) {   // This is the first age we're seeing
                        highest = age;
                        lowest = age;
                    } else {
                        if (age > highest)
                            highest = age;   // This is the new highest age
                        if (age < lowest)
                            lowest = age;    // This is the new lowest age
                    }
                }
</script>

    <button id="myButton" onclick="checkAge();">Go</button>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.